# VS Code cannot find python package

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a local python package installed in my environment. I can use the package with no issues and the code runs. Unfortunately, VS Code does not recognize the python package. I have selected the correct interpreter. I assume something is wrong with my launch.json file. The json file currently looks like this:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        

    ],
    "python.useIsolation": false,
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/venv/Scripts/python",
}
```

I would appreciate your help! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: is odhdefinitions an external packages that you installed via pip or so or is it an internal module that you coded yourself and that belongs to your project?

Comment: You should differentiate between *launch,json* and *settings.json*.

Comment: odhdefinitions is a python package that I developed. I install the package via pip with: pip install -e ..\odhdefinitions\

Comment: Perhaps VS Code implements some non-standard extension (I would guess so based on what the comments say), but **the JSON format does not allow for comments**. "Unfortunately, VS Code does not recognise the python package." - this is not clear: **does the code run as expected**? Is there only a problem with the IDE's hints, or is it actually failing to find the library at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a json file and specified the location of the package odhdefinitions:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "venv/Scripts/python",
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "C:/some_folders/ODH/odhdefinitions"
    ]
}
```

This is the settings.json. This solves the issue.